# Filter list of map using Enum.reduce

Tags: elixir

I have a map as

```
%Subject
{
    sub_id: 1,
    content: %{
               sub_name: "oracle",
               type: "code",
    },
    publisher: "quantum",
    ouby_id: "afc5a6e23208",
    region: "USA",
  }
```

I have a list as follows

```
[
%user{id: 4, name: "kane", status: "A"},
%user{id: 3, name: "Harry", status: "P"},
%user{id: 5, name: "Tom", status: "A"}
]
```

I want to filter **User** with status: "A"  and create a new map as

```
[
%{id: 4,name: "kane", sub_id: 1, sub_name: "oracle"},
%{id: 5,name: "Tom", sub_id: 1, sub_name: "oracle"}
]
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Are the values always `sub_id: 1, name: "oracle"`?

Comment: @AdamMillerchip Yes.. %Subject map is going to be the same but we are not supposed to hard code the values in the new list...

Comment: If they are always the same, why do you need the `Subject` struct? Also, you can't have two `name` keys in the same map.

Comment: I notice you've been asking basic map questions since April. I really think you'd be better to try to figure these sort of problems out by yourself now, rather than asking for the solution here every time.

Comment: @AdamMillerchip thank you for pointing out the name. As for the need for Subject. I have a list of subject struct, which goes through Enum.map, and for each subject struct I get a User list. So I have to prepare a separate map using content of both. I hope this explains.

Comment: ok, then you can replace `1` with `subject.sub_id` and `"oracle"` with `subject.content.sub_name` in the answer below (probably, assuming the subject is called `subject`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using a combination of `filter` and `map` would be better here. You didn't explain why `Subject` was necessary, so I just hardcoded the values you said would always be the same.

```elixir
[
  %User{id: 4, name: "kane", status: "A"},
  %User{id: 3, name: "Harry", status: "P"},
  %User{id: 5, name: "Tom", status: "A"}
]
|> Stream.filter(&(&1.status == "A"))
|> Enum.map(fn map ->
  %{
    id: map.id,
    name: map.name,
    sub_id: 1,
    sub_name: "oracle"
  }
end)
```

Result:

```elixir
[
  %{id: 4, name: "kane", sub_id: 1, sub_name: "oracle"},
  %{id: 3, name: "Harry", sub_id: 1, sub_name: "oracle"},
  %{id: 5, name: "Tom", sub_id: 1, sub_name: "oracle"}
]
```

Comment: Maybe `Stream.filter(&(&1.status == "A"))` → `Stream.filter(&match?(%{status: "A"}, &1))`?

Comment: Also a brief explanation of why `Stream.filter/2` and not `Enum.filter/2` would be extremely helpful for future readers.

Comment: Yeah I lost motivation when I realised it would fall on deaf ears.

Comment: I actually wrote the `match?` version first, but changed it to `==` because I thought it was clearer.

Answer (score 3):

Despite the solution by Adam is perfectly correct, I’d better go with [`Enum.reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3).

```elixir
[
  %{id: 4, name: "kane", status: "A"},
  %{id: 3, name: "Harry", status: "P"},
  %{id: 5, name: "Tom", status: "A"}
]
|> Enum.reduce([], fn
  %{status: "A"} = elem, acc ->
    elem =
      elem
      |> Map.take(~w|id name|a)
      |> Map.put(:sub_id, subject.sub_id),
      |> Map.put(:sub_name, subject.content.sub_name)
    [elem | acc]
  _, acc ->
    acc
end)
|> Enum.reverse()
```